# How to better name modal buttons "Cancel Request" (submit), "Cancel" (cancel)?

Tags: user-behavior, text, modal-dialog, intuition

One modal-box asks the user wether they want to really cancel the request. Now there are two buttons (submit) and (cancel), but how to best name them? All other modals use text like "proceed" (submit) and "cancel" (cancel) - but wouldn't it be confusing to use "cancel request" and "cancel"?

What would be better options?

Comment: is this not pretty much the same as http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35753/what-to-call-cancel-when-cancel-is-already-the-default-action/35777#35777?
Try to get rid of the modal dialog. Label the button with what it does: *Cancel Request* or *Send Request*

Comment: @Lothar_K, to be fair, this was asked *months* ago, whereas the linked one was asked **yesterday**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So if I'm not mistaken, if I'm really reading this correctly, the Cancel button Cancels the Cancel button? It sounds like it could easily confuse folk.

What is the tone of voice like in your system? I like to use real English as it allows for more precise descriptions, so I'd have something like "Are you sure you want to cancel?" with "Yes, please cancel" and "No, thank you"

Maybe something can be done with the question wording leaving you with a closed question and therefore a boolean. "You are about to cancel this record, are you sure you wish to proceed?" would leave the users with Yes/No options avoiding the word 'Cancel'

Comment: Oh, thank you TJH, nice idea! I like what you suggested about: are you sure you want to proceed? -> Proceed/Cancel. The problem is that the dialogs are really small in size, so the text on the buttons should not be sooo long..

Answer (score 5):

**Never use the word "cancel"**

Why is the word "cancel" so problematic? "Cancel" can be understood differently at different conceptual levels:

1. Cancel the *dialogue* and close it
2. Cancel the *service*

What happens when the two levels have to contradict, exactly opposite meanings?
For example:

- For a dialogue to cancel downloads <kbd>OK</kbd> means cancelling the download and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> continuing the download!
- For a dialogue to reset to factory settings <kbd>OK</kbd> means cancelling any changes you've made in the settings and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> means **not** cancelling them!
- And finally, as you asked: For a dialogue to cancel a request <kbd>OK</kbd> means cancelling the request and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> **does not!**

**Solution**: Don't use the word "Cancel".

Instead, say:

- <kbd>Stop downloading</kbd> and <kbd>Continue downloading</kbd>
- <kbd>Reset</kbd> and <kbd>Leave as is</kbd>
- <kbd>Withdraw the request</kbd> (as proposed by @Pesikar) and <kbd>Submit the request</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You could name your **Cancel Request** into something else like **Withdraw Request** to prevent confusion with the Cancel of the action in your application.