# What to call "Cancel" when "Cancel" is already the default action?

Tags: copywriting, confirmation, messagebox, cancel

**When attempting to cancel a service or setting, "cancel" is the default action. What should the normal "cancel" button be called?**

Redbox uses a playful "just kidding", which may not be appropriate in all circumstances.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24051/

Comment: Skype has [a good example of what *not* to do](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/9956/6046)

Comment: How about `Yes / No ` ?

Comment: I got massively thrown out by a pop-up like this today! I think it was in Anno 2070. Great question!

Comment: Related http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/should-i-use-yes-no-or-ok-cancel-on-my-message-box

Comment: Seriously dude! I think what you have up there is really good... I am not a UX guy (as of yet) but, from my point of view, I kinda liked it! 'Cancel now' is really cool... u have also put red-alert-ish stuff on it... so, yea its cool... dont change it :)

Comment: Inspired by Heng-Cheong Leong's answer and deworde's critique on it: **Never use the word «Cancel».** For downloads say «Stop downloading» and «Continue downloading». To cancel a setting or not, say «Revert settings» and «Leave settings as is», and so on...

Comment: Additionally, except in very specific cases always ask positive questions, they are much easier to process quickly. As in the examples below: 'Keep subscription', rather than 'Don't cancel subscription'.  It's much easier to parse a positively-framed question than a negatively-framed one.

Comment: Relevant: https://twitter.com/jjg/status/309748030469443584

Comment: If RedBox's "Just Kidding" button is too playful for the context of your application, you could easily replace it with "Go Back."

Comment: Relevant: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rkQ1C.png

Answer (score 375, accepted):

My suggestion: never use the word "Cancel" in the default action.

To cancel a subscription, you can, for example, say "Remove Subscription" or "Unsubscribe."

To cancel a download, you can, for example, say "Stop Downloading".

To cancel a setting, you can, for example, say "Revert Settings".

Comment: I agree with this answer the most; users are conditioned for "Cancel" to always be the safe way out of where they currently are. Using it for a button with a destructive outcome is a terrible idea.

Comment: -1: Doesn't answer the question. The question is not "what to call confirm", but "what to call *cancel*". If the question is, as above, "Are You Sure?", you've answered what to call "Yes", but not what to call "No"

Comment: "Yes"/"No" buttons are [not good UI](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/should-i-use-yes-no-or-ok-cancel-on-my-message-box).

Comment: @deworde the implication is that once the confirm button text is changed, the word "cancel" is able to be used for the cancel button.

Comment: @KitGrose Not good, as if you're planning to cancel a subscription, having any button labelled "Cancel" is confusing. The assumption is that "Cancel" always means "Don't Do X", whereas in this case, "Cancel" is what I *want* to do.

Comment: @KitGrose that sounds really bad if the action clearly is a "cancel" action, even if you rename the action button

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with this answer. Also, to answer the actual question, I've seen a few sites use the wording "Never mind" to back out of a "Do you want to cancel X?" dialog.

Comment: This answer makes sense in theory and likely in many cases (+1)... but "Cancel my Subscription" was all that was in my mind as the Redbox user  when I took the screenshot - not "Unsubscribe" or "Remove". It would seem that the user's intent and mental model should trump interface copy consistency.

Comment: This answer is not just about the button. It's about the whole action. Don't use "Cancel" for anything _at all_ other than the safe action.

Comment: @deworde and BenBrocka; point taken. You're both right.

Comment: Perhaps we shouldn't name this task "Cancel Subscription" in the first place?

Comment: I disagree with this answer. In many cases, I think the default action in a dialog should be Cancel. In fact, in any dialog where the result are destructive, the default (safe) action should be the cancel option. That includes this case.

Comment: @HengCheongLeong Problem is that "Cancelling a Subscription" is older than computers, so you fall peril to that other great UX fail: "Bug: User can't find option. Reason: Doesn't know our crazy future lingo. Resolution: Works As Poorly Designed".

Comment: Obviously this is one place where usability testing will be helpful, but my gut feeling suspects that for a user who understands "Add Subscription" or "Subscribe to ..." will be able to understand "Remove Subscription" and "Unsubscribe from ...", without the application or website needing to use the phrase "Cancel Subscription".

Comment: +1 Great answer. Often answers that attempt to rephrase a question are poor ones but IHMO anyone that thinks "Cancel" is an appropriate name for a dialog button that does anything other than cancel the dialog is dangerously bad at UX.

Comment: Totally agree. Switched from Windows "OK/cancel" to Linux's "Save/Don't Save". Much better. Don't make me read the whole box, I just want to read the buttons!

Answer (score 193):

Here's what Facebook does when cancelling a payment subscription ([Facebook subscription API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/)).

There's no reliance on Yes/No. There's no misleading use of the word *cancel*. Clear explanation and buttons that clearly define the impending action.

[image]

Then they clearly confirm what just happened.

[image]

Skype on the other hand shows what *not* to do. Much confusion!

[image]

---

<sub>**Edit:** Microsoft have since changed Skype's *Cancel* button to say *Close*. It's a pretty lazy effort at improving the situation, but at least it doesn't say *Cancel* any more!</sub>

Comment: Skype expect you to say "OK, cancel."

Comment: Oh wow. Dialogs like that skype one make me very glad that I can always fallback on the 'red x'.

Comment: Especially painful because they even demonstrate a perfectly adequate synonym, "reject".

Comment: double negation -- makes a knot in my head

Comment: Skype designers: Lets also add in the ability to "Do not ask me again" so if you check this box, then pick the wrong answer from misunderstanding, the frustration is only worse!

Comment: Oh lord. I hope the UI designer at Skype lost their job for that one.

Comment: @JClaussFTW: I bet that this dialog is one made by a programmer, not by a UI designer.

Comment: I hate to say it but that Facebook example is really good. A rare example of good design at Facebook.

Answer (score 44):

**Name the buttons for what they do**.  If the default is "cancel", then cancel the cancel should be something simple like **"Don't cancel"**.

I know that it's not ideal to use the word 'cancel' in both of them, but it's the clearest option in this unique situation, and **clarity** is far more important.

Edit:  Some good suggestions from the comments below are to specify what it is that you are cancelling, and to use a term that doesn't include the word cancel - such as "Keep Subscription".

Comment: I think this answer makes sense, but only if the buttons (rather wordily) say "Cancel Subscription" and "Don't Cancel Subscription". Otherwise you have people who will click "Cancel" out of instinct to dismiss the window and will inadvertently perform a destructive action.

Comment: @KitGrose - I'd say "Keep Subscription" rather than "Don't cancel"

Comment: @KitGrose good suggestion. I added it to the answer.

Comment: @NathanLong Also, a good point.

Answer (score 41):

## Rewording

I would try my very, very best to avoid using the term 'cancel' for terminating the subscription. Cancel is generally considered to be a safe action. Here, you are using it in a more destructive sense, thus causing the confusion you noticed.

If you manage to avoid the term 'cancel' for the actual activity, you can resume to use it for the cancel action on the dialog. In the mockup below, I used "Unsubscribe", but you can also consider other ways to express this like "terminate", "end", "remove" or "stop" subscription.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fodQGX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

## Not confirming at all

Alternatively, you could consider getting rid of the confirmation message completely. Instead, you could display something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP0878.png)</sup>

You could then also send the users a message by email saying essentially the same thing, and also allowing them to change their mind for a limited time.

Comment: +1 for adding the "I changed my mind" link in the resulting dialog.

Comment: The first diagram's coloring, to me, is misleading. The positive affirmative action is the unsubscribe, and the green on the Cancel is counter-intuitive. Something to think about and test.

Comment: @trisweb: I did not spend a lot of time carefully thinking the colors through, to be honest. The reasoning was that the unsubscribe is the destructive option, while the save option is the cancel option. However, I guess you are right, and this does require more thought and testing before putting it in use. Good think that that wasn't the main point I wanted to make :-)

Comment: I think this answer is the best, but, as has been pointed out, having a red button for *Go Ahead* and a green one for *Stop and Go Back* is a terrible choice.

Comment: @CarlSmith: I have removed the colors from the mockup. I wanted to focus on the wording, not on the color usage here.

Comment: @André Nice one. It was a shame to see a really good answer get side-tracked by an irrelevant oversight in the illustration. +1

Comment: I didn't notice the link at first, so it might be better to have it as a button.

Answer (score 24):

**Keep Subscription**

Avoid generic defaults (Cancel/Ok, Yes/No): *label the buttons with what they actually do!*

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkz6AT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Pretend users do not like to read the dialog-text and with luck perhaps 5 or 7 syllables per button. Be short, be clear, use positive imperatives. Avoid negation like *"do not cancel my unsubscription"* or *"don't cancel"*. Place visual highlight on the option that the user requested, as it is done by UX itself (compare Save Edits and Cancel).

**Explanation** Other answers already questioned the usefulness of this dialog in the first place, since your question specifically ask for the button text I will forgo this discussion and just point out that offering an undo is often a better option than a confirmation dialog.

My observation is that people often scan or quick-read instead of really studying the text on screen. This is also discussed in this UX thread [Should alert boxes be avoided at any cost?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4518/should-alert-boxes-be-avoided-at-any-cost) Minor and not so minor details are often overlooked, such as a little "not".

Apart from just overlooking the little words on screen, it has been shown that negative statements are notoriously difficult to understand. For examples senior citizen have trouble when medicine comes with instructions as of what *not* to do, children are bound to do what you tell them *not* to do, or see the [Debunking Handbook](http://www.skepticalscience.com/docs/Debunking_Handbook.pdf) why you should not repeat what not to say.

Generic *Yes/No* buttons can become very confusing, when considering questions such as *"Don't you have password?"* As you observed a similar reasoning holds for *Cancel* and *Ok* buttons.

Finally consider that your audience might have their attention reduced, so keep the button text short, clear and simple. Consider someone stressed and tired: have mercy and be parsimonious with words. This may result in a certain tension between accurate and clear labels on one side and being short, sharp and simple on the other, here a certain finickiness is required to find the right words for a good compromise.

> “I didn't have time to write a short letter, so I wrote a long one instead.” 
>   -- Mark Twain

Answer (score 21):

Use something like "No, I want to keep my subscription" and "Yes, cancel my subscription".
This way the button clearly says what it does. Otherwise people would think that 'Cancel' stands for Cancelling the Dialog Box

Comment: I think that keeping Yes and No in the buttons still causes confusion though.

Comment: If you use a title like "Cancel Subscription?", this would no longer be ambiguous.

Answer (score 20):

I would like to propose a different approach to subscription cancellation.

Instead of confirming that they want to unsubscribe, assume that they were acting intentionally:

[image: Unsubscription dialog mockup]

If the user doesn't click on any buttons on the dialog, they should be unsubscribed in an hour or five. If they dismiss the dialog with the "goodbye" or "(x)" buttons, they should also be unsubscribed in an hour or five.

If the user clicks on the "oops..." button, they should *not* be unsubscribed. This allows the user to make the fewest number of steps to unsubscribe from whatever service they're subscribed to.

More often than not I find myself having to sort out how to unsubscribe from annoying marketing emails, and it would be wonderful if I could spend less time confirming that *"yes [insert service here]'s email is a spammy pile of junk and I no longer want to receive it"*

The other important point to make, is that this is your opportunity to win people back. If someone's leaving because of a small bug that can be easily fixed, it's better to find out sooner rather than later.

Comment: I kind of feel like the "Oops, I didn't want to unsubscribe" should be the green icon in this case. More for marketing purposes than for ux. It makes me want to click the "Goodbye" option. Nonetheless, I think it's a good idea.

Comment: I love actually just doing what the user asked to do and then providing an undo in case of an accidental click. I wish I could up this a few more times.

Comment: I'd make the Oops green, and not even bother with the Goodbye. I think the X in the top right is enough (might make it bigger and red though.)

Comment: I wouldn't like it if "goodbye" were red. I hate it when I make a decision perfectly within my rights, then software tries to make me feel guilty about it because it doesn't want me unsubscribing from marketing material. I _hate_ that.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the shown image had a good idea of emulating the user's thoughts, some other good ideas would be:

- Nevermind
- Abort
- Undo
- Done
- Get me out of here!
- Call off
- Zap

IMO: *Nevermind* and *Done* are the best.

Comment: IMHO - 'Done' will confuse the user. 'Zap' can be slightly confusing too. Rest all are fine. 'Get me out of here!' will do the job perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I believe "Yes" and "No" buttons would be best, provided that the title of the window is clear.  For example:

## Cancel Subscription?

### You chose to cancel your subscription, are you sure?

"Yes" and "No" buttons would be very clear in this case.

Why is this better than other options?

1. The question is short, clear and can't be interpreted in more than one way. Yes it does require that the user read the title, but the question is so short and clear it is read at a glance.
2. This approach also gets the user's attention, which is a good thing, as he's about
   to cancel a subscription, so you want to make sure he's aware of what he's doing.

Comment: Perhaps Yes and No in context would be better, like "Yes, cancel my subscription" and "No, don't cancel my subscription". However, the downside would be ending up with larger buttons.

Comment: "Yes" and "No" buttons are *never* clear, because they require the user read the dialog text.

Comment: @chaiguy that's the point.  You want the user to understand exactly what he's doing. Once the user has read the question, there's only one way he can interpret the "Yes" and "No" buttons.  This is a good thing.  You don't want to the user to unsubscribe when he didn't mean it, and on the flip side you don't want him to stay subscribed when he's not interested as that would only irritate him and lessen the chance he'll come back in the future. If you can make him read a short and clear question, and I believe I gave a very short one up there, it's best IMOHO.

Comment: You may want the user to read the dialog, but that doesn't mean they are going to. You need to design the interface to be accommodating. Remember, you as the designer are catering to the user, not the other way around. You don't get to dictate what the user does.

Answer (score 1):

What about just going with the answers to the question "Are you sure"? You can just say yes/no, or if you want then you can be more personal/user-friendly and do:

YES - go ahead  and NO - changed my mind

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr Never use the word «Cancel».**

Why is the word «Cancel» so problematic?? «Cancel» can be understood differently in different conceptual levels:

1. Cancel the *dialog* and close it.
2. Cancel the *service*.

What happens when the two levels have contradicting, exactly opposite meanings? Examples:

- For a dialog to cancel downloads «OK» means canceling the download and «Cancel» continuing the download!
- For a dialog to reset to factory settings «OK» means canceling any changes you've made in the settings and «Cancel» **not** cancelling them!
- For a dialog to cancel a subscription «OK» means canceling the subscription (duh!) and «Cancel» **does not!**

**Solution**: Don't use the word «Cancel». Examples:

- «Stop downloading» and «Continue downloading»
- «Reset» and «Leave as is».
- «Unsubscribe» and «Keep Subscription».

<sub>See https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/35844/28034, a very similar answer of mine.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a less seen and most spoken "Forget It" or "Leave It"

An end user is always confused of buttons, whether OK, UPDATE, CLOSE, CANCEL etc. For example, if he goes to an "Edit Profile" page and sees a button cancel, he might think that he is going to cancel his account as such. So colloquial words would be more appropriate than conventional as far as websites are concerned.

Comment: Why would this be a good option? Can you add some explanation here as its not a very useful answer without some reasoning and explanation.

Comment: Yes. An end user is always confused of buttons, whether OK, UPDATE, CLOSE, CANCEL etc. For example, if he goes to an "Edit Profile" page and sees a button cancel, he might think that he is going to cancel his account as such. So colloquial words would be more appropriate than conventional as far as websites are concerned.

Comment: @VenugopalM You should add that to your answer.  Always try give an answer that helps people understand why they should do X or Y.

Comment: Those sorts of buttons could confuse those who are new to the English language and not familiar with common expressions such as "forget it" and "leave it."

Comment: @EvanTeitelman That's possibly true, though these phrases work the in the few languages I know. But what about "Do nothing"?