# Alert box wording

Tags: copywriting, alerts

What do you think would be a good alternative word to 'Cancel' on an alert box. An example message is:

You are about to change your password, press confirm to change or cancel to ...

Then I have 'Cancel' and 'Confirm Change' buttons.

I don't want to repeat the word 'Cancel'.. so what would be a good alternative. revoke, abandon or abort? What does anyone think?

Comment: See [What to call “Cancel” when “Cancel” is already the default action?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35753/what-to-call-cancel-when-cancel-is-already-the-default-action)

Comment: My question is different. The default action is not 'Cancel' it's just one of the buttons on the dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

> You are about to change your password.
>
> Press 'confirm' to change or 'cancel' to leave your password
>   unchanged.