# Is there a standard list of the most popular modern web usage terms/labeling?

Tags: guidelines, labels, language, natural-language

I am working on style guidance for a enterprise app. The name of the UI components within the app is not consistent. Is there any standard list of web name, terms or labeling as a reference for making a decision on which name to choose? 
e.g, use submit instead of OK, use sign in stead of log on.

Answer (score 1):

The guide below lists consistent terms for various actions and even shows how to spell things in American English as they value consistent spelling and capitalization across action buttons.

http://www.uxmatters.com/aboutus/uxmatters-style-guide.php

---

The **verbs** *you* use will vary greatly depending on your target audience (old, young, technical, non-technical, American, British, etc.)

Here are some general labeling guidelines to follow and links to additional information while building your guide.

### 1. Use a verb instead of OK

A button that says Format is better than a detailed explanation of what you are about to do followed by a button that says OK.  See more examples in the following thread...

[Should I use Yes/No or Ok/Cancel on my message box?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/should-i-use-yes-no-or-ok-cancel-on-my-message-box)

### 2. Cancel isn't always clear

The word cancel usually tells the user they can back out of an action without saving any changes (similar to saying `never mind`)

Read the thread below for more information on when cancel isn't clear...

[What to call "Cancel" when "Cancel" is already the default action?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35753/what-to-call-cancel-when-cancel-is-already-the-default-action)