# Android pop-up wording if confirming is canceling an action

Tags: android, popup

Running into a case where I need the user to confirm the canceling of an action. Not sure what the correct text here is for the button. 'Yes' and 'No' make the most sense to me but the Material Design guide https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html# discourages that. Maybe I can change the main text? Anyway, what I have below is somewhat confusing. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: could you share more details about the particular actions?

Comment: Cool question! I like it a lot :)

Comment: This question seems like a duplicate of [this very popular existing question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/35753/11687)

Comment: @BatlaDanny think of it like canceling an order. you've requested it but you have the option of canceling it

Comment: @KitGrose yep, good find

Comment: @ono the question linked to by Kit Grose should cover it. in case you particularly want an example for an order cancellation interface, check this out: http://quehow.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/how-to-cancel-order-flipkart-step6.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to consider:

1. Reword the answers. I guess, when you need to cancel "this action", that action has an actual name. Then the opposite of canceling is keeping it. Then the popup may state something like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

2. Another option is to cancel the action and then provide a non-modal popup to undo the cancellation.

[image]

Comment: I like the 'Keep'. Might go with that.

Comment: @ono After further consideration I've updated my mockup to match your original question, rather than rephrasing it.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmations must not ambiguous. The user must not try to interpret what the options will do. Make each option as specific and clear as possible. Also, omit unnecessary words.

For example if the action of the user is the deletion of a record, the message dialog should look something like this :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwj7GX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: The problem itself is 'Cancel' it generally means to cancel the pop-up