# What is the opposite of Cancel?

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, mobile-web, popup, confirmation

I am working with order page. When the user presses on <kbd>Cancel Order</kbd> button, he should choose one of the following:

1. Cancel order.
2. (opposite of cancel) order. (this choice means don't do anything with order)
   by default, this choice on other cases should be "`Cancel`".

What is the opposite of cancel on this case?

Keep in your mind, `cancel` is usually what you press to decline an action in a UI situation, and here on my second choice, I am trying to do that.

Comment: Is this when an order is already placed? So will the user be cancelling an out standing order? Or is this one of the last steps of the order process?

Comment: first choice,order already placed

Comment: **confirm order?** or am I missing something?

Comment: Process, Proceed, Affirm, Confirm, Action would all be the opposites to Cancel in many cases.

Comment: [**Proceed**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/proceed): to carry on or continue any action or process.

Comment: In Windows, OK is typically the opposite of cancel, in forms, Accept can be the opposite of cancel.

Comment: [Similar question.](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35753/what-to-call-cancel-when-cancel-is-already-the-default-action)

Comment: No one suggested "**continue** this order"? As a marketing bonus, it's quite engaging.

Comment: If I did something (e.g., click a button) to indicate that I wanted to cancel something, and a dialog came up with a "Confirm" option, I would select it to say, "Yes, I confirm that I want to cancel." Something like "Keep processing" ("Keep shopping," if appropriate) seems intuitive. This suggests that we should not be getting to this point via "Cancel"; as [Ken Mohnkern says](//ux.stackexchange.com/questions/105143/what-is-the-opposite-of-cancel#comment169355_105147), "cancel" normally means nothing is going to happen.  The first command should be "Discard this Order."

Comment: in addition to @TafT , **Resume order** ?

Comment: @Migz possibly although Resume suggests it was paused or halted, I think most of mine suggest a continuation of a smooth process.

Comment: Buttons should be [OK Cancel] and [Cancel Cancel].

Comment: Continue gets my vote, it suggests you are carrying on the process, rather that starting the process (Confirm, or Proceed)

Comment: 'Cancel' is a negating action; it is intentionally broad to apply to whatever your scope/context was previously.

Comment: **Do not cancel order**

Comment: `lecnac` is way more googleable than any of these others.

Comment: I would use "Decancellate", with a hyperlink to a 20-page explanation of what it does.

Comment: Keep in mind, cancel is usually what you press to decline an action in a UI situation, and here on my second choice, I am trying to do that.

Comment: Maybe "commit" (like in commit a transaction)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to call "Cancel" when "Cancel" is already the default action?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35753/what-to-call-cancel-when-cancel-is-already-the-default-action)

Comment: I think The question here more specific

Comment: I'd go with 'Proceed'

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Cancel might be too vague. I always like to be more descriptive when asking users to perform a quite destructive task. This often reduces any anxiety users might have.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmfmm6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**Edit**
As LightnessRacesinOrbit made me realise in the comments, mixing up buttons with links that act like buttons (or in this case it's a button styled as a link) might be confusing. This thought might be unsubstantiated, but nevertheless, I'm adding the following mockup:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpVFeX.png)</sup>

Comment: This also stops the users from reacting instinctively to the buttons they were used to, like "OK" or "Cancel", and makes them actually read what this unusual (for a dialog window) sequence of letters means.

Comment: @Ruslan That's key. I can't count how many times I've "auto-clicked" a button because I assumed the meaning of an overly-simple label... only to be wrong.

Comment: In my example, the Yes button draws more attention, just like an OK button would be auto focused to draw attention to it. The revert button is styled down. In my test I've never encountered someone pressing the wrong button. This, however, does not prove this pattern is better or worse than your basic Ok, cancel confirmation popup in that area. I did have some verbal feedback of users saying they liked how clear it was and how they're still unsure whether the action is still performed or not performed when pressing just ok or cancel. IMO, this validates the anxiety reference in my answer.

Comment: Good answer. I'd like to add something... Because "cancel" is so often used to indicate that a state is being left unchanged, I'd suggest not using that word at all. So the button could be "Delete Order," then the confirmation can be "Are you sure you want to delete this order? [Yes, delete the order] [No, keep the order]."

Comment: @KenMohnkern I don't think I agree. Cancel also means [to revoke](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cancel) and is in this case applicable.

Comment: That's true, @PaulvandenDool. But I think it's better in general to use words that are less ambiguous.

Comment: Basically, you want the buttons to be self-explanatory, without having to read the dialog box. The one weakness I see here, is that the default should be non-destructive. If "Yes, cancel this order" is focused, a user may accidentally press enter, or autopilot to the focused button, and cancel their order. If the user accidentally selects "No, keep this order", nothing happens, and the user can go back in and select the correct option afterwards. The user will have to recreate the order if they accidentally select "Yes, cancel this order", adding unnecessary hassle.

Comment: @PaulvandenDool: If the order has been issued, but not processed, I would suggest "Issue cancellation request" rather than using the "Cancel" as a verb.  Note that in most situations where a "Cancel" request would prompt a conformation dialog box, no action will be processed until the user responds, but in an order-cancellation situation if the user doesn't do anything the order will likely proceed as planned.

Comment: Actually,  I use the same one but I write  choice number 2 as the following: (No, go back)

Comment: I'd agree with William that this breaks the rule about the highlighted option ( which would be the one you action if you press return ), being the one which saves data not destroys data.

Comment: Mixing buttons and links this way is really terrible, from a semantic standpoint. But from a usability standpoint it can be quite helpful. I'm torn! Argh!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "terrible, from a semantic standpoint". How so? You mean that something that looks like a link should behave like a link? If so, you might be quite right.

Comment: @PaulvandenDool: Basically, yeah, but adding to that .. if your system "violates" that principle and makes links act like buttons (or makes buttons act like links) then that's one thing but you should do it consistently. This example mixes it up within the space of two lines! Or does it....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The mockup was hastily set up. I didn't know it would get this much traction. I might want to improve on it. But it's not so much as a link that acts like a button, it's a button styled as a link.

Comment: @PaulvandenDool Oh hey I'm not complaining about the mockup. I see this approach all over the web in real life. I'm just thinking out loud, I suppose. I'm saying that buttons styled as links (especially when there is a button styled as a not-link right above it) should theoretically be bad and wrong, but are not only commonplace but (in my experience) fairly user-friendly, which is interesting. Maybe it's just me. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I get that, but nevertheless, you do have a point. And I thought it worthy to update my answer.

Comment: See, I think the one with the button-as-link is less confusing, user wise haha

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've revised my edit to reflect I misunderstood you ;)

Comment: I like the idea of just a single button, with the "No, keep this order" textual link being significantly smaller and offset somehow.

Comment: Red colored cancel button still attracts user attention, which may result in a human error, accidental click. I suggest to swap places, see my reply below.

Comment: @Ades: but it SHOULD attract attention. And also alert. The button is to *confirm* the cancellation of the order

Answer (score 49):

Have you considered giving the user an **undo button** instead? It **reduces the cognitive overhead** because no choice actually has to be made in the normal case and **reduces the input** from always having to do two actions (click cancel and then confirm/other) to only a single action when the user actually wants to cancel:

[image: example undo flow]

Wireframes made in [Pencil](https://github.com/evolus/pencil/).

Comment: The undo option is really good. Currently it is described in material.io (http://bit.ly/2m1vgly) and I think it is extremely user friendly.

Comment: Undo is the way to go!

Comment: This is not the same as the 2 button scenario, if the user don't know that it's possible to undo the cancel operation afterwards (since it's invisible before the action). It can, for example, lead to users afraid of pressing the button. In some cases it works, but it should really be tested.

Comment: Google and Amazon both use this pattern extensively. Of course users who don't actually want to cancel the order should be afraid of pressing the button. Users who click it by accident still have a way of saving themselves from themselves though, which they wouldn't do if instead of an undo button they get a confusing dialogue, and then click the wrong thing.

Comment: @HenrikEkblom, if the user doesn't know that they will be required to confirm the 'cancellation', doesn't your comment also apply to the other answer? Personally, one advantage of the 'undo' option is that it is not necessarily a one-time choice - i.e. the user can possibly go back later and undo the action in some way (although this is OT for this question). FWIW though, I think that both the top two answers have their place and I find that this SE often leaves me thinking more deeply about the range of UX choices available, even for such a seemingly simple question.

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood what you were saying.  Deleting previous comment.

Comment: Most users that click a first "delete" button will confirm. Instead of annoying them with an extra action because, "of course I want to cancel the order, that's why I clicked the cancel button in the first place!". For those rare (?) times that it was indeed a miss-click, the undo option will make them all warm and cozy towards your fantastic app.

Comment: If "Undo" truly means that the underlying data processing action that the user has invoked (by clicking the 'cancel order` button) has completed or will eventually complete if no further action is taken, then I reluctantly accept `undo` as an option... (Hyperbolically) thinking, doesn't the ability to 'undo' degrade over time (e.g. at some point undo is impossible because the deletion of the order is complete (not that anyone actually does hard deletes any more))... speculating, if I left my browser open with the 'undo' option displayed for 2 days, should undo still work?

Comment: @Neoheurist In general (as in, this is behaviour I've seen in places like Gmail), as soon as you navigate away from the page (or close the application, or whatever is the equivalent action) undo is no longer available. There will also be a server side timeout - deleting and undoing isn't meant as some sort of crude backup solution. Undoing is for the rare situation where you clicked by accident, not for when you need your manager's approval. The reaction time is expected to be measured in seconds or possibly minutes, not hours or days.

Comment: Instead of using Pencil for wireframes, did you realise that this Stack Exchange has a built-in Balsamiq mockup tool? When answering (or asking questions) there's a button at the top next to the 'insert image' button that triggers Balsamiq.

Comment: @JonW Doesn't work without Flash 10. Which presumably is not available on Linux, since I have the very latest Flash plugin available on Arch Linux.

Comment: Jef Raskin in The Humane Interface argued for the Undo button, too.

Comment: I love this approach! I'm the kind of guy who always mumbles "Yes, I want to, why do you think I click there in the first place?!?" when I see a confirmation dialog.

Comment: My first reaction would be to include a button that says 'Nevermind', or 'Go Back'.

Answer (score 11):

The first thing that came to mind given your example was:

1. Cancel order
2. Proceed with order

One goes back, the other one forward. Maybe too forward-ey though?

Answer (score 9):

"Cancel" in computers has very well defined meaning of "don't do the thing". That's the root of the problem here, as here the thing we're doing is "cancelation(sic) of an order".

I believe the best way would be to avoid using the word "cancel" to describe an action, rephrase it to something like "revoke order" or "dismiss order". It's not natural, but at least not as confusing as "yes, cancel" - "no, proceed".

Comment: Thing is, in the world of placing orders and buying things, "cancel" also has a very well-defined meaning (arguably more so) that you can't just swap out willy-nilly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the fact that the word "cancel" has two well-defined meanings, in different context, and that in this situation they are in direct opposition, is exactly why the term should be replaced with something else. Perhaps "Discard order"?

Comment: Also consider people with only basic knowledge of English. Using computers might have taught them that cancel means "don't do it", but they might not know the other meaning of this word. I have learned the first meaning way before the second one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But author is already forced to swap out one of those cancels. I'm merely pointing out that swapping the other may be possible. It's up to him to decide.

Answer (score 5):

I know another answer with Yes / No buttons has already been given, and accepted, but I just want to add this.

If a button says something and then a confirmation dialog pops up saying "are you sure you want to ..." and the same word, there is often a knee-jerk reaction to hit "Yes" without giving it much thought.

So the user hits a button called "Cancel" and the dialog says "Are you sure you want to cancel?" then the natural reaction is going for Yes. That's the button I clicked, so that's what I want to do!

A better approach would be to briefly describe what would happen without using the word "cancel" again. Or the words "are you sure".

> This will remove your standing order. Proceed?
>
> <kbd>Yes</kbd>      <kbd>No</kbd>

Comment: Personally I find this confusing. Why not just directly label the buttons?

Comment: What with? "Cancel" and "Cancel not"?

Comment: @MrLister Yoda would understand "Cancel Not"

Comment: "Yes" and "No" are almost never the right buttons to use in any alert dialog, especially one with potentially destructive consequences like this one--they rely on the user carefully reading and interpreting the question, which [people are generally bad at doing](https://blog.codinghorror.com/teaching-users-to-read/). Pretty much every major user interface style guide advises against it, and recommends labelling buttons with the consequences of each action.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the opposite of "cancel" is "continue", at least in your scenario.
After someone presses "cancel order", the simplest confirmation would be:

**Do you really want to cancel this order?**

- No, please take me back to the ordering screen so I can continue with this order.
- Yes, I want to cancel this order.

I always provide the "Oops" choice first, when it's a negative action.

It slows people down and makes them reread the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that the "cancel" button should be visible for the user, but in the case, it is the only button on the page, the user could be influenced and will be not in your interest that he change his decision to make that order.

I suggest you add a disabled button with "Confirmed" because he confirmed the order when he finished it or a button with "Edit" if he has this option.

Answer (score 1):

- Back (back to previous page, back to listing, back to search, ...)
- Exit
- Quit
- Leave
- Close (not a good choice. Might be obvious to a developer when the order is being displayed in a windows, but ambiguous, since orders can be closed as well...)
- Keep Order (this one has been mentioned above)
- Discard Changes

In general, it makes sense to add a noun to the verb. "Close Window", "Cancel Order", "Cancel Edit", "Cancel Cancellation", ...

You might also consider to use graphics to enhance the text. For example, a "happy smile face" might provide a hint which button to press to not break things. Of course, some users will consider anything graphical as frivolous and maybe will even flag any graphics they encounter as a critical bug. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

"I change my mind"
"-go back to order"

I've taken this approach and it has proven intuitive in the tests I've conducted

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different terminology rather than Cancel with a greater meaning and understanding what would happen.

I think the button should say something like the following:

[image]

1. withdraw order
2. draw-back order
3. pull-back order
4. discard order

then, use the confirmation as offered by @PaulvandenDool

Comment: The problem with this is that it needs to be easily understandable. I would not know what 1-3 means.

Answer (score 1):

Objective of this confirmation box should be **to reduce human error** due to accidental, impulse or out of habit clicks. Therefore:

1. "***Yes, proceed to cancel***" should be in a text-link format (underlined and blue color to be optimal). This lets users to make a deliberate choice to click it.
2. "***No***" should be in a button form and should be in a 'selected' state by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a standard confirmation dialog...

```
 "Are you sure?"
 [Cancel] [Ok]
```

<kbd>Ok</kbd> confirms the operation and cancels the order. <kbd>Cancel</kbd> cancels the operation, ie. the order is not cancelled. "Cancel" always aborts a confirmation dialog / operation.

User hits <kbd>Cancel Order</kbd> on the parent page and <kbd>Ok</kbd> on the confirmation dialog - seems pretty intuitive and they don't need to read anything.

Comment: Neither “Cancel” nor “OK” are a valid answer to the question “Are you sure?”. You cannot honestly be suggesting this.

Comment: Argh!  So I press [Cancel] if I _don't_ want to cancel it?  And something different if I _do_ want to cancel it?  This dialog doesn't need to ask "Are you sure?" - I'll never be sure which button's the right one to  press.

Comment: "Familiar does not mean intuitive." I can't find the article again, but that was one of the first things I read when I discovered UX. That something is common does not mean it is intuitive. Try to explain otherwise to someone who has never seen that "standard confirmation dialog" before.

Answer (score -3):

Can also be something like this:

> Can you please tell us if you want to cancel your order?
>
> `Yes, that's precisely what I am willing at doing.`
>
> `No, I don't really intend to do such a thing.`

Comment: But [users don't read.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/teaching-users-to-read/)

Comment: So many down-votes, yet the most up-voted and accepted answer is this, just worded differently.

Comment: Sort of makes sense since the question is largely about wording....