# "Activate" / "Enable" + "noun verbing" or simply "Verb noun"?

Tags: copywriting, interface, wording, perception

A popular chatting application has the global option "Enable buddy icon animation". Would this be better phrased as "Animate buddy icon" or not? And if so, is this a general rule? For example, replacing "Enable SSH logging" with "Log SSH" seems to cry out for another noun like "output" at the end. But that might be an exception since "log" can also be a noun.

Comment: This thread has some content that you might find relevant: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35210/should-all-button-text-start-with-a-verb/

Comment: "Animate buddy icon", to me, sounds like it'll make non-animated icons wiggle around just for the sake of animation.

Comment: @Yamikuronue +1 That's an excellent answer - That it *forces* animation rather than *enables* it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to **make a distinction** between an action that causes a **single event** to happen, and an action which causes a **state change**.

**`Delete X` is an event** as it will happen once and X will not continually be deleted without the user selecting `Delete` again. **`Enable animation` is a state change**, as from that point on the animation will happen without the user being needed.

So I would keep to language that implies a state (such as enable or activate) for state changes such as `Enable logging` or `Enable animation`. And single event verbs for single event actions such as `Delete` or `Highlight`.

---

The `Enable SSH logging` vs. `Log SSH` is a subtle distinction, but an important one.  When someone selects `Enable logging`, it is clear that from this point on something will be logged, whereas the language in `Log SSH` implies that a log will now be generated for recent activity.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the state change. I still think it's clear from context - a global settings dialog, separate from the context where buddy icons appear - that we're talking about a permanent state change, but I can see how it could be misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

The verb in "Animate buddy icon" does not refer to the action user may perform. He will not animate, but he can enable/disable the animation.

Hence I'd say "Animate buddy icon" may sound for the user like "Animate it once, now". Still, it mostly depends on where it is placed. Should it be a checkbox in settings, it would mean "enable/disable the option" while a button in the chat window might make the user think it refers to on click, one time (and thus on demand) animation of the icon.

I would do it like this - strip the verb from the option name, so that it sounds "Animated buddy icon: disabled" and move the verb resembling the action user may perform to a button [Enable] placed next to it. Upon pressing the button, the option would change to "Animated buddy icon: enabled" and the button to [Disable].

Comment: The button solution has been [discussed elsewhere](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan), and I agree with the accepted answer that it's difficult in practice to understand how this works.

Comment: Clarified the question to make it clear that it's a *global* option, not something to do once.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad question and there's no *right* answer. However, I'll like to give my 2 cents.

It depends on a lot of things, from your users to what form elements you use. The "Animate buddy icon"-label needs a radio button group (Yes/No) or a similar set of options (like a dropdown). "Enable buddy icon animation" only requires a checkbox.

I would go for whatever is most describing and also fits in the screen that you design. However, there are **other concerns you need to assess**. For example: you can force input to the radio button group but you can't force it using the checkbox (unless it's a T&C-style checkbox that the user *has* to agree to).

Comment: I don't agree that 'the "Animate buddy icon"-label needs a radio button group ... or a similar set of options'. Anybody who knows how check boxes work are aware that whether it is checked or not directly corresponds to "Yes" or "No".

Comment: Regarding "you can force input to the radio button group but you can't force it using the checkbox": It is possible to not select anything in a radio button group ([HTML example](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_radio_button.cfm)).

Comment: @l0b0: you don't really animate the buddy icon, you enable the animation. In this example it may be clear, but what about the second example: would "Log SSH" be clear enough? What about enabling large text sizes? "Large text size" doesn't cut it. "Increase text size" might. It just depends on the wording you choose.

Comment: @l0b0: regarding your second comment, that's why I said: "you CAN force input". You don't need to, but you can explicitly ask for a yes or a no. You can't do that with a checkbox, then you can only enforce if leaving it unchecked is not an option.