# How do we ensure our staff read instructions aloud?

Tags: copywriting, content, instructions

[As Jakob Nielsen demonstrated](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/how-little-do-users-read/):

> On the average Web page, users have time to read at most 28% of the words during an average visit; 20% is more likely.

We have a business application used by call center staff to carry out transactions on customer accounts. Our testing has consistently shown that our staff **don't read** important messages aloud to the customers.

For example, we have a transaction that makes a significant change to a customer's account. We want staff to read out the 3 bullet points (around 40 words) to the customer on the phone. This is to ensure that the customer understands the consequences of the transaction. The vast majority of staff skip over the text and try to click 'next'.

We have tried reducing the copy as much as possible, and using visual prompts to highlight important text, but these haven't made a measurable difference.

#### What can we do to encourage staff to read out important messages in our business application?

Comment: Block the UI for x-amount of time before allowing the user to continue. It's bad UX and might piss off the user, but it serves the point.

Comment: Keep the text to be read as short as possible. That'll increase your odds. Beyond that, there really isn't anything you can do. People just don't read; it's a fact, and good designers accept it.

Comment: Might be too complex a tool for a tiny problem, but might be feasible with today tech: Activate speech recognition, and enable "next" only after the speech recognition has heard something sufficiently similar to all listed bullet points. (Maybe enable an override, but only if going that route is more annoying than conforming and reading the text)

Comment: It's because the users don't care. I often don't care about instructions/notices. Build your system so that it doesn't matter that they don't care.

Comment: /me reads the title and the quote, skips the rest of the question

Comment: It sounds like the users who are not reading the bullet points are your own employees, is that the case? If so, then you don't have a UX issue, you have a personnel issue.

Comment: @JanDvorak So, wrap up instructions in quotes, got it

Comment: Supervisors should be  spot checking calls to the customer to make sure the procedures are carried out correctly. If they are not then (potentially disciplinary) action needs to be taken. This should be standard in a call centre operation (and was in my last job).

Comment: If you ever figure it out, I'd like to know.

Comment: I'm seeing a yawning disconnect between "*read to the customer on the phone 3 bullet points*" and "*to ensure they understand the consequences of the transaction*". How does the former ensure the latter in any way? And why does it matter? Is it a CYA measure? Are you making the change because you have to, to do what the customer asks? Then they will surely agree whatever you say. Is there no 'undo' if they don't like it? Build one. Is there no ton of legalese they have already agreed to, saying "we may change your account if you ask for service X"? Can you add that somewhere?

Comment: short answer: you can't!!!!!!!!

Comment: The only real solution is to audit the users and discipline them for failing to correctly perform their duties.

Comment: Try delivering the information with video clips rather than written information ?

Comment: If they click the button before 15 seconds have passed, give them a 2 or 3 word warning that they MUST read the text before clicking (effectively blocking them from clicking the button until they read the text, but still showing the button so they don't spend that time looking for the button).

Comment: Depends on if your users prefer the carrot or the stick...

Comment: @AlexHowansky: got this right. You can't make an end user read instructions if they don't want to; but employee users are different beast. If they habitually skip your standard operating procedures (SOP), they either need training so they know the SOP or they need to be reprimanded for it.

Comment: Are you sure that the messages really do need to be read each time? For example, if a customer has multiple transactions, do they need to be read the message every time? If the user has to retry a transaction because of a failure/error, do they need to read it the second time? Are you allowing for these possibilities in your testing?

Comment: Does your business have time-based KPIs? A lot of call centre workers are under pressure from their managers to meet a calls-per-hour quota or minimise time-per-call. If it's impossible to read the text and still have time to meet their KPI targets, they're not going to read it.

Comment: Make your users tick those bullet points. Add an extra bullet point saying `I changed my mind` and abort if your users tick it.

Comment: Dig deeper into WHY the call center people aren't reading the text they've been told to read. I'm going to agree with @Robyn - your call center folk are probably being rated on their call times. If that's the case, then nothing you do is going to help when their raises or perhaps their continued employment is conditional on keeping call times low. The incentive of being fired if you aren't fast enough is going to over-ride any UI changes you make.

Comment: After clicking "Next", show a huge, screen-filling message saying "User account deleted after charging $500 as a final payment." or something similarly disastrous. Put a small "Attempt to undo" button in the corner. When clicking it, have the system simulate some hard work (by showing a progress message and delaying things for some seconds), then display a concise message to the point of: "Phew. Luckily, nothing happened this time. Next time, READ THE MESSAGES BEFORE CLICKING NEXT." ;)

Comment: Is there a reason an audio message can't be played instead of relying on the operator/employee to read the message? That way, if it's built into the system, it's possible to only allow the 'next' button to become active once the system has played the message.

Comment: I agree with @AlexHowansky that this is definitely a personnel issue with some UX components. I bet you would get some interesting answers from that perspective over at [workplace.se].

Comment: @JanDvorak At least you read the quote. I just read the title and then skipped right to the comments.

Comment: @KodosJohnson : Title? What title?

Comment: I am so tempted to say, *Just tell your staff that all phone calls are now being recorded for quality review purposes*. :) But of course I'm not condoning that you _lie_ to them - so if you can't/won't record the interactions, then do what many organisations do - have quality review people randomly walking around the call centre to overhear interactions and take notes of what staff are doing right/wrong and then let them know. To me this is more than just a UX issue and there's only so much you'll achieve if you focus on it purely from that angle.

Comment: @Robyn is right. Unless reading this text counts as minus two ~ five minutes of call time, they will not read it because it can costs them their employment. Incentive to read must be as big or bigger to work, and has little or nothing to do with UX.

Comment: Well it's extremely easy. You just need to equip every computer with a microphone, then some voice-to-text library, which activates the "Next" button when it "hears" the written pattern and...oh, sure, you need to remember the noise cancellation aswell... and the accents...  you know what? No, it's not easy at all....

Comment: Would you mind just showing a simple wireframe or mockup of what's currently used?

Comment: What if the customers themselves say "yeah, yeah I know, just skip the notice"? I'm that kind of customer.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can't force them to read something, but you *can*:

- Mitigate the cases where they're **instinctively skipping it**.
- Remove the benefit for those **intentionally skipping it**.

As Alan Cooper puts it in *[About Face](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118766571.html)*, you need to *"hide the ejector seat lever"* and **break their flow**.

- **TL;DR:**

  - Users who ***intentionally*** skip instructions should be held accountable.

    - Also **remove the benefit** of skipping the instructions.
  - Users who ***accidentally*** skip instructions should have their flow broken.

    - You should only break the flow if it's actually important.
    - I suggest a timer method which breaks the flow without annoying the user.
    - But this is often a sign that you're showing too many unnecessary messages to users.

*Note: The OP requires that the user reads the bullet points **out loud** to the customer everytime*.

---

## 1. Use a Timer

Some critical systems I've encountered **use a timer** to make the *Next* button inactive for a set amount of time.

By breaking their flow you stop them from instinctively pressing the button. The length of the timer should represent the minimum amount of time it would take to read the text to the customer.

Once the user has finished reading the points to the customer, the button will already be selectable and thus **requires no effort on the users part**.

This means that it **won't annoy the user**, unless they're breaking the rules by not reading the bullets to the customer.

It also means there's **no benefit to *not* reading out the instructions**.

---

## 2. Use checkboxes

Another suggestion is to **put a checkbox next to each bullet point** and force the user to select them to make the *Next* button active.

Put the instructions at the end of the paragraph. Something to the effect of:

> Select the checkbox beside each bullet point to continue.

This would ensure that the user **has to parse the information to some extent** before continuing.

This method is often used in online banking:

[image: Natwest Online Banking Message Acknowledgement]

But in this example, Natwest uses the method too trivially by including it under *every* notification.

#### Only use flow-breaking methods when *absolutely* necessary...

... use them too regularly and they'll become part of the flow rather than breaking it.

---

## 3. This might be a deeper issue altogether

Perhaps you're **showing them too many unimportant messages**? Causing them to instinctively dismiss all messages.

Alan Cooper also says to "**avoid unnecessary reporting**":

> If you must use them, reserve notifications for events that are outside the normal course of events. If your users benefit from knowing things are running smoothly, use some more ambient signal.

---

## 4. What about the users who are intentionally not reading the bullets?

UX can't provide much help here, but you can review their conversations and  **make them accountable** for not following protocol.

One way UX can help is to **remove the benefit of not reading the instructions**. The timer method I describe above does this.

Comment: I really like the checkbox idea. In general, requiring an action in order to "force" a user read a text is a good approach

Comment: The given example is a *horrible* example of the sort of thing that you want to use this on. Do this sort of flow-breaking on enough trivial fluff, and you get into a "boy who cried wolf" situation where users won't read anything and just hunt for the checkbox and the confirm button. To actually break their flow, you need to make sure it's "out of the ordinary" enough that they pay attention to it. These sort of techniques rely on users not being acclimatized to warning - waste it on faff and you reduce the effectiveness on the stuff you *need* users to pay attention to.

Comment: I only included it as an example of how it would look. Using it for regular notices would indeed weaken it's impact, but the OP has indicated that we would only use it for important messages. I'll add a comment to the post clarifying that I've only included as an example, and that you shouldn't use the method for "trivial fluff" :)

Comment: If you do implement this please add a way to disable the nagging in some advanced settings menu. Not all of us are stupid and some do read through warnings - don't make it extra annoying for those users.

Comment: @AndréBorie This is why I prefer the timer method. By the time the user has read the bullet points to the customer (which they *must* do), the button will be selectable.

Comment: Some people read faster than others. And if I've read it 100 times I don't really want to read it again *unless it changed* (maybe enforce a timer the first few times but then let them click through it until the message is changed).

Comment: @AndréBorie For this reason I mention that the timer should be set to the minimum amount of time required to read the bullets to the customer. As long as the pause is enough to break the flow.

Comment: OP wants the user to actually read, out loud, the text to the customer every time. It's not for people to read the text in their head. I don't understand most of the comments here.

Comment: @the_lotus I think that's where some people are getting confused. I'll add a note to the beginning of my answer re-iterating that the OP needs the user to read the answer to the customer *out loud*.

Comment: As someone who worked for a company doing telephone account management for bank customers - pretty much this exact use case - I assure you that adding a timer simply means the person reading will click the button sooner, as soon as they get an inkling that this is what a customer wants.  They will simply cancel out if they were wrong, but the timer will have elapsed by the time they get confirmation even without reading (that is, unless you greatly handicap the interface around this).  "Use checkboxes" is similarly bypassed.  "Ask fewer questions" is a nonanswer from a legal perspective.

Comment: You would indeed handicap the interface around this to ensure it is effective. The specific case I've seen this used effectively is in insurance call centres, where the user *must* read the legal script to the customer to adhere to government legislation.

Comment: This is why clear and obvious labeling, as the OP has indicated he is doing, is important. As the OP's users are in **direct verbal contact** with the customer, I think it can be assumed that they've had some form of orientation, and expect at some point to be presented with text to read to the customer. Of course, only further user testing will prove whether the checkbox or timer method is more effective for the OP's particular users.

Comment: Re: making them accountable; if this information *must* be read to the customer, one 'nuclear option' would be to let your staff know (maybe even on the same page) that calls are randomly reviewed, and if they miss reading the bullet points enough times, it will count against their performance.

Comment: @user117529 Good idea, or even telling them *why* it's important would help. However, I've tried not to discuss the accountability point in detail as I feel this is more related to organisational management than UX :)

Comment: @JoelTebbett I see your point more clearly -- going that route would involve UX concerns, but potentially different ones than the original question.

Comment: What about returning customers? Are they forced to wait again?

Comment: @vsz Assuming that it's a legal requirement that the bullets are read out each time, then yes. If not, and there's no benefit to the user in repeated viewings, don't display the message after the first time and this becomes a non-issue. But it's dangerous to assume that the customer will remember the bullets indefinitely. So if it's important, the benefit of reading the bullets each time will outweigh the inconvenience of making an undesired, permanent change to their account. And if it's not so important, why are we reading them bullets at all? :)

Comment: With proper design, it seems to me that by actually providing a clickable checkbox to click could help the process flow by assisting the call centre personnel to remember reading out the text (especially if there are multiple items). This is not obstructivistic but assisting strategy especially if actually clicking the checkbox is non-mandatory. For some people motor activity helps to execute sequential steps especially when they are not at their best alert level. Otherwise the problem of OP is not about user interface design but of enforcement of compliance.

Comment: I like 1 - the psychology being "Well, I have to wait around whatever happens, I might as well read the stupid bloody bullet points for the thousandth time".

Comment: Timers will make users want to meet you in a dark alley if they ever have to test or troubleshoot the application....

Comment: Then disable the timer when troubleshooting/testing? It's common practice to disable features which aren't being tested during development :)

Comment: @JoelTebbett: Unfortunately, it's also a common occurrence that it's the side-effects of those features that end up as bugs on the customer's machine because they were not discovered while testing.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Well yes, that's if you don't test entirely. But regardless, functional testing is a matter of implementation, which is outside the remit of the UX StackExchange :)

Answer (score 55):

We are not talking about Facebook visitors, but professional users in the business environment. Simply hire people who understand what they are doing. No UX improvement can be a replacement for that.

Comment: To add to your point (which is a good one), the business can also incentivize "compliance". That's standard practice in many enterprise environments.

Comment: Agreed. You can only train/educate clients, but you can control staff

Comment: Your answer to _How do we ensure users read instructions?_ is _fire your users_?

Comment: @RichardEverett If an employee is instructed to do X and they consistently don't do X without recommending any other course of action or suggesting an improvement then they are to blame (and replace). There surely is a UX side to this story, but employees are usually expected to be either obedient or resourceful and initiative.

Comment: @RichardEverett Not really. Think about it in two layers - one is the customer that calls into the call centre; he needs to get his warnings. Second is the employee that presents the system to the customer - his *job* is to present the warnings. If you can't do your job, you're usually disciplined or fired. It's not like the instructions are hidden or dense - they literally show text you're supposed to read to the customer, word by word. If you can't do that, why would I pay you? I don't need the lawsuits that are going to follow.

Comment: The fact that your users don't have a choice (employees, monopoly customers, etc.) shouldn't be an excuse for designing a poor UX. Your goal should be to remove friction for your users, full stop.

Comment: In business environments, software workflows aren't always "easy". Proper product design is required, but so is employee compliance. The ability to correctly use required software is a regular part of clerical job interviews and training. And incentives are a regular part of keeping the team on target (in addition to software innovation).

Comment: @KPM: What exactly is the "friction for [the] users" you are talking about? Reading out a text aloud? Well, sorry, that's simply what they're paid to do. We're not talking about a task that becomes unnecessarily hard due to poor UX. We are talking about a task that users just refuse to do.

Comment: As you can tell from my phrasing, this was just a general appreciation. I only said "ok well whatever you think of this particular case, don't forget that, folks". Please don't over-interpret my words.

Comment: I agree with that one, the others address the issue only for classic web client. Where here we have staff not following instructions.

Comment: +1 I would add, this has to be a part of their training. During the training on the software, they should be faced with this situation and forced to say things loud literally. Also make sure this is clear from the software (I think you have this done).

Comment: If one internal user skips an important part of a process, deal with the user. If many are, deal with the process. "A company that ignores the user experience of internal applications and information systems will alienate the largest and most future-oriented portion of the talent pool." Ref: http://www.saxonypartners.com/roi-of-user-experience-design/

Comment: @TimGrant: "ignores the user experience of internal applications" - the user experience of displaying some lines of text that need to be read aloud. "the largest and most future-oriented portion of the talent pool" - the talent pool of people who are able to read some lines of text aloud. Yes, I know the employees probably also have to bring other skills and knowledge, but I think abstract guidelines go only so far.

Comment: @TimGrant I think a big problem is that in this case, it is not the UX that is the faulty part of the process.  The part of the process which seems to be broken is in either the training or quality control of the employees.  If your employees are consistently forgetting/avoiding part of their job; you shouldn't rely on changing the user experience to fix personnel problems.

Answer (score 25):

## Don’t make them read it

I'm guessing your call center staff is like everybody else's:
**Unmotivated and paid as little as possible.**

How do you make them do anything? You do it for them.

## Record it

Record the critical messages and embed them in the application. Make the employee click a button to play a recording of the message as part of their workflow.

**Pros:**
Use your best voice talent on the message; force employees to play the recording to continue.

**Cons:**
It's weird to communicate via recording; your employees feel even more like monkeys than they did before

## It's a business decision

Weigh the engineering cost of that feature against paying the employees more to create stronger performance incentives.

Comment: Another con is your customers will almost certainly notice it is a recorded message and may tune it out as such.

Comment: Using a recording was going to be my suggestion and many call centres do just that. Can make it a little less weird by getting the employees to record the messages themselves, then people on phone will be less likely to ignore it. Ultimately, this is all going to be academic soon, as AI call centres take over. AI doesn't mind reading the exact same messages thousands of times per day.

Comment: @PeterGreen That is also likely to happen if they simply read the text aloud.

Comment: I agree that Recording is the answer. But don't use a recording, record every conversation that the call center staff has. Then police those recordings via transcribing them or using voice recognition to count (and de-merit) those that continually skip the required steps.

Comment: Of course, your employees still *could* read out the text out loud - adding the option to play a recording might make the actual reading seem more appealing in comparison. At least for those who at least *try* to get a smidgen of satisfaction from their job :)

Comment: +1. The employees may actually appreciate being able, while the recording is going, to take a moment to mute their line and sip some water or whatnot.

Answer (score 17):

### EDIT: AFTER QUESTION TITLE CHANGE

Now that the question has completely changed, I want to edit my answer to fit the question.

This question, now, is definitely slightly beyond **just** user experience. *Ensuring* the staff's activity is like setting up regulations for their behaviors which cannot be achieved by UX changes.

**However,** If the sound controls are out of the staff's reach, an **audio cue** like,

## "Pay attention to our executive for the upcoming information"

should do the trick. It has certainly made sure that the stewards and stewardess' on flights go through the safety demos *flight after flight*.

### BEFORE QUESTION TITLE CHANGE

As Joel Tebbet mentioned in his answer, forcing an action from the user is a great way of getting them to read. I do not disagree but, it doesn't truly **make** them read it.

How many times have we actually read the T&C despite clicking on the "I Agree*?

My suggestion is to go with the **step-by-step** walkthrough approach. In the OP's case, just two steps: One to inform, the other for the user to convey that they've read it.

[image: Step-by-step walkthrough]

I agree that not having the **Skip** option makes the user hyperventilate but for *important* instructions (like, in case of banking applications), this might be a good idea.

*PS: I know this isn't the best approach but I am certain this would get more users to actually read.*

Comment: I actually believe this is the right answer: put each important bullet point in a specific step. As a designer, I believe that's the best you can do to ensure the users has seen all the steps. You can't force the user to read anything anyway without being a real obstacle to him.

Comment: But if it's *genuinely* important that your user does something (as in the OPs case), it's necessary to obstruct them. If "the vast majority" of users are skipping the message, it's almost definitely because they're instinctively used to hitting *Next*, not because they can't be bothered to read it. As Cooper describes in About Face, you must break their "flow" to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: @JoelTebbett -  Don't you think the *I agree* checkbox breaks the user's flow? Like I mentioned before, I do not disagree with your answer but I highly doubt that it would make them actually read. After your edit, I would like to add that the **timer** is a good gimmick but guess what? People would just pick up their phone and scroll through social media sites and let the timer run out. I don't think you can convey the message of, "you need to read" by forcing them to look at a countdown

Comment: But you're still presuming that the issue is that they can't be bothered to read it, when it's more likely they're dismissing the message out of instinct. If you only show the timer on important screens, they'll know that their action is required. Also note that the OP says that the user needs to read the points out loud to the customer, so they'll be on the phone to or physically with a customer at this point.

Answer (score 14):

Most of the answers here are applicable to a typical self-service application, but you've specifically asked about a call centre situation. This means the UX should be optimised for users who are familiar with the screens, and you have more control over your users' behaviour (because they are working for you).

Typically in call centres staff have a strong incentive to minimise the call time, and they will do this by cutting corners when possible. Not reading out that message is an easy corner to cut to reduce their call time by 20 seconds.

There are two basic approaches you could take:

1. **Convince staff that this message is too important to skip.** This might be through an on-screen change, or it might be through a separate training session that covers the purpose of the messages and the consequences if the customer is not aware.
2. **Prevent the staff from saving time by skipping the messages.** This could be by adding a timer to the screen, or it could be through call monitoring and disciplinary procedures if the message is not read out.

Answer (score 9):

> The vast majority of users skip over that text and just try and click 'next'.

Given that your users are obviously looking for the 'next' button, why not change the text of that button to something more indicative of the consequences of their action?

For example, instead of a button that says [image: Next], you could have one that says something like [image: Buy Subscription] instead.

See also: [Should I use Yes/No or Ok/Cancel on my message box?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/9946/19076)

## If an action is really dangerous…

…you could opt to force your users to type out their action. For example, GitHub uses this when deleting your account:

[image: Github's account deletion prompt, which asks the user to type 'delete my account' to confirm their action.]

Of course, this route should only be chosen if an action would have such serious, irreversible consequences that it's worth inconveniencing the user like this.

Comment: But wouldn't users also know the more explicit button texts after having used them for the 10th or so time, and thus still click them immediately?

Answer (score 9):

The deeper issue here, if I understand certain details in the question correctly, is less the UX/psychology of skipping instructions/text that the Nielsen quote is referencing (which is often best dealt with by refactoring so as to not need *separate* instructions), but instead **making sure that your own personnel are correctly following a script and reading it across the phone to a client.**

While it's true that in this case your personnel are themselves users of the *software*—while the client across the phone is a user of the *service*—the issue is a bit different from the usual UX seen with people failing to read text, as instead your personnel are failing to perform their **job duty** in rendering that text into spoken dialogue so that the end user client can even be presented with the related informational content at all.

### QA and general process conceptualization

How are you checking that your personnel are staying on script in general? You need to have a process (or multiple processes in place) for this. Your personnel are not new or naive users of this system: they are **trained employees**. They are presumably using this system continuously throughout the day. They are effectively (or will be) expert users of this system, and the considerations change in this case from someone who is seeing each element for the first time, and from audiences who represent a varied makeup of skill levels and familiarity with those elements. While UX of the software is still important to make sure they are not needlessly struggling with the system or being made to feel like they are wasting time on *needless, suboptimal* interactions with the system, given their repetitious use, remember that their training is also a UX element of the overall system (beyond the software).

### Agent Feedback, Client Communication Refactoring

Before we lock things down, consider that if your agents are skipping something repeatedly, they may think they have a good reason to do so.

This does not mean that their reasons are necessarily "correct," but it may be worth finding out why they are skipping the problem parts and what their thoughts are regarding them. If your agents do not think it is important to tell the clients the information that is presented in the script, maybe it is worth reconsidering how that information is worded to the client, and whether that information can't be presented differently or more directly and succinctly, perhaps in the form of a direct question to be answered by the client for each part of that information rather than as simply a set of statements:

> Your account is going to … Because of some things that maybe you don't
>   care about but we're going to tell you anyway because we think they're
>   important to us and so they should be to you too And that means your
>   account is also going to …
>   So you're ok with all of that?
>
> **pause for input**

versus

> Are you ok with your account … ?
>
> **pause for input**
>
> Please affirm that you are also ok with your account … due to this change
>
> **pause for input**
>
> Do you have any questions or require further explanation?
>
> **pause for input**

Note that refactoring communication to the client into concise, encapsulated queries instead of long statements also helps prime the agent for actually reading the query to the client, as they need the client's input for the application.

When conversing over the phone, breaking up information into small pieces that each require confirmation from the client also ensures that if the client *doesn't* understand *part* of the process, they have an opening to ask related questions. When communicating over an audible medium, and particularly where there are no related visual cues between speakers, it is important to give opportunities for communication to be both ways.

Otherwise, it's easy to see where someone such as an agent might assume that all of that information is either too much or must be ultimately irrelevant, because the client could be assumed to either already know it or be overwhelmed if they don't and it's presented all at once.

### Set Script, Stay on Script

Make the entire process more of a set script with an emphasis on **staying on the script.** This helps ensure that the entire process of **reading from the script** is rote and that they do not deviate from what is presented to them to read. Make sure it is emphasized in agent meetings and training that deviations from the script may incur liability for the company, because they are acting as representatives of the company in reading from the script. What types of disciplinary action are in place for agents who continually deviate or otherwise potentially create liability issues for the company? Notifying them of that should be included in training, meetings, and individual feedback sessions/performance reviews.

If you do not have a set script for the entire process, and are instead letting agents communicate through the process themselves up until the point of the text you want them to read, I suggest that you potentially have a problem with your overall process. No one likes reading rote phone scripts, but they are necessary for consistent service, and they also provide degrees of assurance to agents in terms of what is ok to say and what isn't to a client. The rote aspects of reading from a fixed script for the entire process help ensure that important details aren't left off (like the ones you are currently having trouble with).

- While it's fine to explain why something is important, one mistake I often see made in UX in general is explaining the importance of something that is not optional, at a time or in a format where it distracts from immediately continuing a task properly. If the agent is supposed to read the entire script verbatim, then you should not be explaining why certain portions are more important than others: their job is to read the entire script, not to make decisions about which parts they deem ok to skip. Having an explanation of the significance of part of the script mixed into the script itself is unnecessary: I would keep any explanations of significance about specific portions to things like meetings and trainings. The core understanding the agent should have when reading the script is that they have to read the entire script *as their job duty.* While knowing the "why" is a comfort, psychologically, and can certainly be explained when someone is interested in understanding in a different context, it can also become a point of confusion and unnecessary timely cognitive load when it occurs in the midst of performing the task and when there is not *actually* a choice present in the performance of that task, which makes it both extraneous and distracting from the agent's actual work.

### Script Controls, Flow interruption

For crucial parts (and *only* to be used sparingly, or you risk creating far too much unnecessary frustration and the same rote behavior you were trying to avoid), make the agent initial that part of the script. Do not use buttons, it's too easy to simply click through a button to dismiss it, and people are effectively trained to do so by generalized customary rote (all of the various forms that require ticking off an agreement to something that is rarely if ever actually ready by anyone). Provide a text entry, and for the purposes of assigning personal responsibility, make them initial it themselves (not with the client's initials). You can have them enter their initials at the start of the script, if needed, as an agreement to read the entire script, and then check these portions against those initials (I'd recommend against using their recorded full name in the system for that purpose: not everyone initials with the exact initials of their full legal name and/or some systems fail to properly represent a person's full name properly). This helps emphasize that they are responsible for having read aloud those portions. If the client's agreement is also something that needs to be specifically recorded and having a strong record of that agreement is important, I would suggest having a separate input for recording that agreement.

### Design Language

Use consistent **and separate** design language for both instructions to your own agents and verbiage/dialogue your agents are supposed to read verbatim to the clients across the phone.

- Keep extraneous verbiage *directed to the agent* to an **absolute minimum**. Keep it clearly separate from the dialogue meant to be read to the client. These are presumably people who will be trained on performing their roles over the telephone to represent the company to the end user clients over the phone. They will presumably be reading these scripts repeatedly quite a lot in their job roles. Not only do they not need to see an explanation, but it also can make their jobs harder, in terms of switching between reading something to themselves and repeating as they read something aloud to the client over the phone.
- I would recommend making use of both collapsed instructions that the agent can open if they are looking for help in the middle of a customer interaction and/or using a column layout that keeps instructions for the agent in a separate column from the dialogue the agent is supposed to be reading, so that a very practiced agent can simply read straight down the dialogue column. Even if there are branching options/etc, the column layout helps fix the modality (reading dialogue aloud to someone else) into a clear spatial representation and separation.

Super ugly example of concepts covered, please don't use it the way it is:

[image]

Note that while color was essentially used to convey differences in flow, it's using an inverted scheme for the focus/action items in addition to the change in color, making it usable for individuals who are color blind. Adding a word to indicate that the agent needs to pay attention, such as "STOP!" at the beginning of each related action dialogue may be helpful to also accentuate such dialogues for agents with visual impairments, but ideally would not be needed (training on agent interaction with clients is hopefully the better focus). Another example of visually distinguishing the spoken dialogue from the system interactions with the agent would be to use rounded speech dialogue bordering for the portions to be read aloud, if you wished to have it in bordered regions/etc.

Also please see the above segment on Client Communication Refactoring for a potentially better way to reformulate this over simply having the agent read an entire paragraph/etc to the client all at once.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure it's important to read it once, but what about the second or third time a user does this transaction? I think a lot of times users bypass instructions because they already know or think they know what you are trying to tell them.

Force them to read it once with a controlled progression where they have to press next or check some box. If it's that important, put each of your three points on a separate page. But keep track of who has read it, and offer a bypass the next time. Otherwise, it's going to be a painful experience for repeat users.

Comment: This is very valid point as well. You can make the section be able to bypass or less distractive on the next time repeated presence is needed.

Comment: The question clearly states that the user is required to read this *out loud*, *to the customer*, each time. Whether the user already knows the information is irrelevant, it is the customer who needs to be informed, and it will be a different customer each time so the customer will almost always be hearing it for the first time.

Comment: Perhaps flag "completed" on customer accounts? That way if a customer has heard it already the user can simply ask them "Are you aware of the consequences of this action?" -- if the customer's response is along the lines of "Yeah, I do this 10 times a day", then the user can skip reading it and click Next.

Comment: @DoktorJ: At least if the information is legally required, skipping may not be an option.

Answer (score 4):

Make users ***prove*** they read the instructions.

For example...

#### Part 1

"Here's an important message. Read it carefully, there will be a quiz."

#### Part 2

"Quiz: What did the message say?" (Multiple radio buttons with different answers)

#### Part 3

"Correct answer. Congratulations! You passed the quiz. Now we know you understand the important message." (Or) "Incorrect answer. Sorry, you have to read the message more carefully. Redirecting to message..."

Comment: I like this. When passing the quiz you get a medal and is allowed to click "Don't show this again." You can collect suggestions for the multiple radio button values by first having it be a text field. After a some users have filled this out with wrong answers, use these answers a the wrong ones for the radio button.

Comment: What to do when users try guessing the correct answers instead of reading the message?

Comment: If it is really important stuff - embed a code in the messages, with instructions to write it down, and use it as a password for the next step...

Comment: Since this is a call center problem, the user is likely to come across the scenario multiple times and will "know" the answers. The issue is that they are not _reading out loud_ the message on the screen (for the benefit of the person on the other end of the phone). This does nothing to address that.

Answer (score 3):

I think a lot of answers here are biased because usually user is the target.

Here, we have customer, say bank account owner that wants to change anything via phone call, and user, an employee of the bank where the account is governed.

Obviously, the customer must be informed about consequences their request may/will lead to and user is annoyed by reading the very same information again and again and again...

The mandatory option here is that the customer hears the warnings, who will say that warnings is optional. Is it possible to read the warnings prior the customer is forwarded to the operator?

If not, try to explain it to the users **why** reading it out loud is a must and insist on confirmation, that they understand and accept it. If they still hesitate to read it out loud they may cause lawsuit for you and they are worth sacking.

You can make the calls recorded, which may force the users to follow instructions.

If even this fails, you can try to add voice input to the program, use voice analyser and check the words to be said at given step.

Answer (score 2):

Building on other answers, for your specific use case I propose:

## Timer + Highlight

Time (approximately) how long it takes to read each bullet point aloud to a customer. Prior to enabling the "Next" button, start all three bullets off in a slightly greyed/faded state. Hold for a second to allow them to read the top instruction (e.g. "You MUST read these points to the customer before continuing:"), then highlight the first bullet point. Leave it highlighted long enough for them to read it to their customer, with a tiny bit of extra time for a pause (which gives the customer a moment to absorb what they were just told). Then, fade that bullet out and fade in the second one; repeat for the third. After the allocated amount of time on the third point, fade it out and enable the "Next" button.

The highlighting serves to draw focus to each point, and for those with reading disabilities or the like, provides visual tracking for which point they're currently reading aloud. By disabling the "Next" button the user is forced to read the points aloud, or sit on the phone in an awkward silence as the *purposely* ignore the procedure. Hopefully in the latter case, your jurisdiction and policies allow you to monitor and/or record customer calls, and it'll be fairly easy to call offenders on the carpet: "so, we listened to a recording, and you just sat there and BSed with a customer when you were supposed to be reading the bullet points. Is there any reason you chose to intentionally ignore what was being shoved in your face on the screen?"

Comment: "for those with reading disabilities or the like" - I am not convinced someone with a reading disability is the right person for a job where one of the main tasks is reading out information shown on a screen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper reading disabilities, like most others, fall on a spectrum. It's perfectly conceivable that someone only has minor difficulties reading, and the highlight simply makes the process go a little smoother for them (as well as for those without such difficulties).

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, there is a fixed text that the user (an employee) has to read to a customer and this text appears so often that the user gets bored and skips it.

Additional to the other reasons, it might work to take some repetitive work off your employees, by prerecording the text, so the employee only has to press a button to play the message.

This means:

- You can be sure the text is read exactly the way you like it
- Your employee benefits by having a few seconds where they don't have to talk (which, in a call center, is a quite nice thing)
- The customer gets a few seconds of text that was recorded by a professional speaker in a studio environment, which means it will be easier to understand

Answer (score 2):

Here is a crazy suggestion: Voice recognition to advance to the next screen. Here is the beauty of it, it doesn't have to be good voice recognition. If your voice recognition regularly misrecognizes 30% that is fine as long as you have a 50% match to the script, you can enable the next button. Adjust the match requirements based on actual mean and standard deviation of errors you actually see in testing.

Answer (score 2):

I remember the article where Jacob Nielsen showed his concerned towards the percentage of text read by the users.

3 months back we had a similar problem and that time we used some visual hacks to make the points more visible and intuitive and also some gamification along with some slight and playful animation which made it more prominent for the users what I am reading and what will appear next.

Gamification can help in several ways like, on every bullet point, a user can interact by marking it read, make it a star point and adding a comment and each interaction will have a reward.

a great example would be this thread; you are giving away 100 bounties and to earn that people are literally putting their inputs and hence you can verify that these people are reading your question.[image: just like this]

Still, just a suggestion. All upto you. :)

Comment: So, what comment are users supposed to enter when they encounter the same text for the 10th time? And how do you prevent them from marking each bullet point read immediately without reading it aloud?

Comment: particularly commenting is not the only option but it could be one of them based on the required needs. Gamification doesn't have any guidelines but it is different for every situation and requirements.
One of the help could be, making the text crisp and short and putting a time window between marking the very next bullet point selected.

Answer (score 1):

"We want the user to read to the customer on the phone 3 bullet points (around 40 words) to ensure they understand the consequences of the transaction."

I'd use the checkbox method (see above answer) and phrase the bullet points differently.

Ask the customer:
"Do you agree this change is a big deal?".
[Checkbox] Confirmation received from customer.

So the tickbox indicates that they have received confirmation from the customer, in which case they *had* to read it out aloud.

Accompany this with training, listen to recordings of the calls to ensure they do and take whatever action you deem appropriate if they don't.

Comment: Sadly the checkbox just becomes part of the flow, "click this box then click this button" without any reading necessarily occurring. Do you read the entire EULA in an installer before ticking the "I agree" checkbox and clicking "Next"?

Comment: This is why I included training at the end. The employees must be *trained* to use the script correctly. If it's part of their job description then it's perfectly acceptable to expect them to follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Editing my answer, since the question has since been sharpened.

These are mandatory work instructions. Such as it is, the job of design here is to convey that to the user. Reflect that in the visual hierarchy:

(First element in order, and the most visually prominent:)

"Read the following  3 bullet points aloud to the customer on the phone:"

(Second element in order:)

"Bullet 1"
"Bullet 2"
"Bullet 3"

I echo whomever suggested a **2-step wizard in a modal window.** The best way to increase the user's focus is to take away all competing distractions and force the user to consume the content in the order you dictate.

Think of a those awful pre-roll video ads. We hate them because *we have to view them in order to view what follows.* That stepwise model is actually useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Have the next button read out the text as a recorded message and disable any further action until it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Customers could ask for the consequences of the transaction.

For example

Stuff member's question: "Would you like to hear 3 important consequences of your transaction?"

Customer's reply: "yes" (stuff member is obligated by the customer to read the consequences)

Customer's reply: "no" (customer took the responsibility)

Comment: How do you make the staff member ask the customer "Would you like to hear 3 important consequences of your transaction?"? Sounds like you are just shifting the problem to another piece of text.

Comment: This solution takes in count the second person, its a human dialogue, always made by two. Most answers and the initial question ignore the existence of the customer as part of the system, part of the problem and part of the solution.

Comment: "its a human dialogue, always made by two" - but only one who can directly interact with the system, and who *should* follow usage instructions for the system. "Most answers and the initial question ignore the existence of the customer as part of the system, part of the problem and part of the solution." - rightly so, because if the customer does *not* inquire any further on their own, the solution that relies on the customer breaks down.

Answer (score 1):

Record it once and configure your phone system to play it (obviously without disconnecting either caller) when call-workers press the appropriate button on the phone. They're unlikely to skip it because they get to "take a break" while the message is playing. Most business phone systems support this sort of thing if you dig around in the settings although obviously it get's tricky if there's 50 different versions of the same message.

Answer (score 0):

In general if UI reinforcement of the Business Process is not enough, there are technologies that may be used, but might be expensive for such a short process, but could be developed. What would be needed is :

1. The submit button being disabled in the begging of the Call.
2. Call Monitoring -> The Audio conversations Agent Audio Log would need to be monitored via either Call Recording software or port mirror (only works on VOIP enabled networks) This may be done without customer consent as you are only recording the leg of your own employees.
3. Audio Stream can be sent to Server running speech recognition containing a grammar for the appropriate language and the expected inputs. Some pbx have build in functionality available for this via MRCP or similar technologies also MS  Windows Servers come with build in speech recognition that may be used free of charge).
4. The server that handles the speech recognition should interact with the WebPage (Potentially using CTI or similar technologies) enabling the submit Button.

In short there is a technological path possible. Concrete solution would require a little more knowledge on the type of Call Center Software used, for concrete interest talk to your Cisco , Avaya, or whatever provider you use and ask them for potential information about such a use case.

So as this is possible, sound to me like this type of solution approach would be best described by the German Proverb : "To shoot at sparrows with cannons"

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the crucial goals of an ideal system should be these:

- Users who are following the instructions (i.e. already informing the customers what you want them to be informed of) should face minimum disruption and annoyance or additional steps. i.e. For them the systems should be unobtrusive and in the background. They need not even be aware that anything has changed or that you have systems in place to make them pay attention.
- Users who do not do the task that you want them to should see the system intervene and nudge them to do the task. Worst case the system should even stall till they toe the line
- The system should have as few as possible "false positives" and "false negatives" when it decides its action based on what kind of user it is dealing with on the current call.
- The system should give the user the option to override it in the rare case that the system is wrong.

Here's one thought / solution but this may need a bit more effort on part of the systems designers:

- You already have access to their voice stream
- Voice recognition systems today have reached very high quality with minimal errors in transcription. Easily exceeding 95% correctness even on free form text.
- In your case the text is not free form but highly scripted.
- Suppose your UI shows those bullet points maybe in orange ("the nudge") to start with.
- As the call proceeds the Voice recognition is trying to capture and compare against the script shown in each bullet point. As soon as (say) 50% matching words are found to a give bullet point we are fairly certain that the user has indeed covered that point. So then the system changes the color of that point automatically to say green.
- Unless all oranges turn green the system refuses to activate the next button
- For the rare case that the system makes an error each orange bullet point has an override tick box that the user can tick to indicate that he has indeed read that bullet point but somehow the voice recognition has goofed up and not acknowledged it. This allows for a Plan-B in the rare case without frustrating the user.
- The "override" option can appear only after a certain timeout so that users are not tempted to casually use the override boxes. Users who use the "override" tick boxes more than a certain number of times are identified and manually counselled or any system bugs are identified
- If even better voice recognition accuracy is desired then at the startup phase the system can make each user read the scripted bullet points a couple of times to the system so as to train the system's voice recognition engine.

I realize that this may be a bit of work to integrate the solution but I suppose if it's worth doing then it's worth doing well. Noting how cheap and reliable consumer grade voice recognition has become I see no technical barriers to implementation.

I also agree that this isn't purely a UI-oriented-solution but I think sometimes a more holistic approach leads to a better solution.